# SOQL Help Needed

Tags: soql

I have an object of project organizations that are children of projects.  I want to retrieve a list of project organizations (eventually will be filtered) and then return the unique projects that are associated with them.  Below is what I have.  I think what I am missing is the SOQL statement that will return projects if the project appears in the project organization query.

```
    List<Project_Organization__c> allProjectOrgs = new List<Project_Organization__c>();
    List<Project2__c> allProjects = new List<Project2__c>();
    List<Project2__c> uniqueProjects = new List<Project3__c>();


    allProjectOrgs = [SELECT Project_ID_text__c, Id, Name, Project_Title__c, Category_text__c, Project_URL__c, Lead_Org_Display_on_Website__c, Project_Organizations_RT__c, Logo_URL__c
        FROM Project_Organization__c WHERE Category_text__c='Awarded' OR Category_text__c='Completed' 
        ORDER BY Project_Title__c];



    allProjects = [SELECT Name, Project_Title__c, Category_text__c, Project_URL__c, Lead_Org_Display_on_Website__c, Project_Organizations_RT__c, Logo_URL__c
        FROM Project2__c 
        ORDER BY Project_Title__c];

    uniqueProjects = ??  Something like...
        [SELECT Name, Project_Title__c, Category_text__c, Project_URL__c, Lead_Org_Display_on_Website__c, Project_Organizations_RT__c, Logo_URL__c
            FROM Project2__c 
            WHERE Name in 
                SELECT Project_ID_text__c, Id, Name, Project_Title__c, Category_text__c, Project_URL__c, Lead_Org_Display_on_Website__c, Project_Organizations_RT__c, Logo_URL__c
                    FROM Project_Organization_c
            ORDER BY Project_Title__c]


    return(uniqueProjects);
```

Comment: Make this SOQL first```SELECT Project_ID_text__c, Id, Name, Project_Title__c, Category_text__c, Project_URL__c, Lead_Org_Display_on_Website__c, Project_Organizations_RT__c, Logo_URL__c FROM Project_Organization__c```. Group all names in Set<String> uniqueNames. After that make SOQL ```uniqueProjects = [... WHERE Name IN :uniqueNames...]```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This query should work

`uniqueProjects = [SELECT Name, Project_Title__c, Category_text__c, Project_URL__c, Lead_Org_Display_on_Website__c, Project_Organizations_RT__c, Logo_URL__c
            FROM Project2__c 
            WHERE ID in 
                (SELECT Project2Id FROM Project_Organization_c WHERE  Category_text__c='Awarded' OR Category_text__c='Completed')]`

Replace Project2Id with the API Name of the Parent on Project Organization.

Comment: please use the `{}` command in the editor to format your code properly (select all the code, then apply the `{}`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to execute three queries here. You should be able to get away with only executing one.

```
List<Project2__c> projectsWithOrgs = new List<Project2__c>();


projectsWithOrWithoutOrgs = [SELECT 
                                Name, 
                                Project_Title__c, 
                                Category_text__c, 
                                Project_URL__c, 
                                Lead_Org_Display_on_Website__c, 
                                Project_Organizations_RT__c, 
                                Logo_URL__c,
                                (SELECT 
                                    Project_ID_text__c, 
                                    Id, 
                                    Name, 
                                    Project_Title__c, 
                                    Category_text__c, 
                                    Project_URL__c, 
                                    Lead_Org_Display_on_Website__c, 
                                    Project_Organizations_RT__c, 
                                    Logo_URL__c
                                 FROM Project_Organization__c 
                                 WHERE 
                                    Category_text__c='Awarded' OR 
                                    Category_text__c='Completed' 
                                 ORDER BY Project_Title__c)
                             FROM Project2__c 
                             WHERE Id IN (SELECT
                                            Project_Id__c
                                          FROM Project_Organization__c)
                             ORDER BY Project_Title__c]

return(projectsWithOrgs);
```

This will return a list only Projects that have Project Organizations in one shot. If you also need projects that don't have Project Organizations, then you can remove the second WHERE clause.

Comment: That worked.  Is there a way to pass a variable containing the where clause to the SOQL statement.  I tried the following but am getting errors.


        String statement = '(SELECT Project_ID__c FROM Project_Organization__c WHERE Category_text__c='Awarded' OR Category_text__c = 'Completed')';

        uniqueProjects = [SELECT Name, Project_Title__c, Category_text__c, Project_URL__c, Lead_Org_Display_on_Website__c, Project_Organizations_RT__c, Logo_URL__c
            FROM Project2__c 
            WHERE ID in :statement];

Comment: How do you paste code in a comment?

Comment: '   String statement = 'ID in (SELECT Project_ID__c FROM Project_Organization__c WHERE Category_text__c=\'Awarded\' OR Category_text__c = \'Completed\')]';

        uniqueProjects = [SELECT Name, Project_Title__c, Category_text__c, Project_URL__c, Lead_Org_Display_on_Website__c, Project_Organizations_RT__c, Logo_URL__c
            FROM Project2__c 
            WHERE :statement;'

Comment: Unfortunately, Stack Exchange has only simple formatting functions available in comments, so I believe there is no way to format for code.

Comment: To accomplish what you're trying to do, you should look into [Dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm). It let's you build a string, and then execute that string as a SOQL Query.